# diophantine equations $x^3-2y^3=1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I'm not familiar with diophantine equations. At most my approaches doesn't give results. I need to solve the following equation
$$x^3-2y^3=1$$
Where $x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$
I know $x=-1,y=-1.x=1,y=0,$ Aware of any other integer solutions. Prove

Comment: Also, if $x$ is even, then $x^3$ is even, and $x^3 - 1$ is odd. But $x^3 - 1 = 2y^3$ and the RHS is even. So $x$ must be odd.

Comment: My first thought is to rewrite as $(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)=(y+1)(y^2-y+1)$ and think about factors, but I don't know if this will help.

Comment: By Thue-Siegel-Roth, there are only finitely many solutions. Page 154, LeVeque, Topics in Number Theory, volume 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have found the only solutions. These things are not so easy to prove. This one is done in Mordell's book, Diophantine Equations, in Chapter 15.